# How can I create a tree without nodes conflicting?

Tags: algorithm, tree, nodes, diagram

I have an issue creating a tree in a 2D layout in a project I'm creating. I will use diagrams.net to try to demonstrate my issue visually.

Let's consider a horizontal tree with nodes branching. I am putting the nodes in 2D coordinates without overlapping them. But I want the child nodes of a node to be symmetrical in relation to one another, simple case for 3-child and 2-child shown:

[image: 3-child & 2-child]

I want to keep this symmetry, but I don't want my children nodes further down to not conflict with each other. For example, let's consider the following scenario:

[image: Conflict scenario]

In this image, node1 and node2 are both children of root node. And node1 and node2 have children of their own but since I am spreading out these children, they conflict. What kind of an approach I can follow to prevent this kind of conflict? How can I calculate how to spread out my nodes so that they only spread out as much as needed without conflicting? The node heights' can also be different so I need to factor that in, but for the purpose of keeping it simpler we can ignore that and factor it in later.

I just want to know how to approach the situation in terms of node geometry calculation; a drawing or pseudo-code or an explanation would all be useful.

Thanks, have a nice one.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with symmetrical? For a moment I thought you meant they should be equally distributed (with equal space between them), but this is clearly not how you have done it for the right-most level.

Comment: Yes I've meant children of a node distributed with equal space between them. The example is shown to illustrate that the children nodes conflict, I may not have made it very symmetrical. Sorry if that was confusing.

Comment: OK, the main idea is to start with the leaves of tree, i.e. at the right side and work from there to the left. If you cannot make it work, please focus your question on an actual data structure, programming language, example data, ...etc.

Comment: Are you stuck on `diagrams.net`, or are you open to `dot` or `pydot`?

Comment: @Neil Currently stuck with diagrams.net, using mxgraph library which is the library behind. It has a built-in horizontal/vertical tree layout but it doesn't work too well so I'm trying to re-implement.

Getting the approach/algorithm down would be good enough for now rather than a library/language specific implementation. I just need to cover base cases and edge cases that might occur.

Comment: `dot` is an entirely automatic layout engine in [GraphViz](https://graphviz.org/) that uses Gansner et al, 1993, Drawing Directed Graphs. You could `dot -Tplain` to extract the positions of the shapes and transfer them to `diagrams.net`, but it seems kind of convoluted. Probably a simpler solution in the software you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you also want parents to be centered in front of their children. Getting nice-looking layouts of trees (and generally, graphs) is an active research topic!

A simple pseudocode should help you to get started:

```
function requiredHeight(node) returns int:
   if (isLeaf(node)) return 1
   total = 0
   for each childNode:
      total += requiredHeight(childNode, depth+1)
   return total
```

Calling `requiredHeight` on a tree root will return the total number of leaves, which as @trincot notes, is a good start for required number of vertical slots. You can use this pseudocode to assign positions to nodes, assuming that each node's height (=number of leaves) has been set with the above code:

```
function place(node, startX, startY):
   node.x = startX
   if (isLeaf(node)):
       node.y = startY
   else:           
       node.y = startY + node.height/2
       totalHeight = 0
       for each childNode:
           place(childNode, startX + 1, startY + totalHeight)
           totalHeight += childNode.height
```

This will center each parent node in front of its children, and should never lead to overlaps of children of either the same or different parents.

Note that it is far from perfect: you can sometimes squish the tree vertically without any nodes overlapping; but this code makes not attempt to do that.